# Dynamic array of char* (or 2d dynamic array of chars)

Tags: c++, shell, pointers

I'm getting funky output when running this code. There isn't a compile error. As far as I can tell, the problem is in my `getArgs(stringstream& ss, int size)` function. The strings are not copying correctly into my char* variables. I wanted a dynamic array of char* to save my command line arguments to. What am I doing wrong here?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

struct arguments
{
    int argc; //number of arguments
    char **argv; //array of arguments
};

void startupMsg()
{
    cout << "******** CS415 SHELL ********" << endl;
}

int countArgs(stringstream& ss)
{
    string temp;
    int count = 0;
    while (ss >> temp)
    {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}

char** getArgs(stringstream& ss, int size)
{
    ss.clear();
    ss.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    char **ary = new char*[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        ary[i] = new char;
    int c = 0;
    string temp;
    while (ss >> temp)
    {
        ary[c] = const_cast<char*>(temp.c_str());
        c++;
    }
    return ary;
}

void printArgs(arguments* args)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < args->argc; i++)
    {
        cout << args->argv[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

arguments* parseCommand(string command)
{
    arguments *args = new arguments;
    stringstream ss(command);
    args->argc = countArgs(ss);
    args->argv = getArgs(ss, args->argc);
    return args;
}

int main()
{
    string command;
    startupMsg();
    //while(true)
    //{
    cout << "user@linux:~$ ";
    getline(cin, command);
    arguments *args = parseCommand(command);
    cout << args->argc << endl;
    printArgs(args);
    //}

}
```

Comment: Use `std::vector`. You have dangling pointers

Comment: Yes, that would make my life much easier. Unfortunately, this is a school assignment and my "arguments" struct must remain as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
    ary[c] = const_cast<char*>(temp.c_str());
```

A good rule of thumb is when you find yourself needing `const_cast`, you're probably doing something wrong. It's not like you *never* need it, but it's quite an exceptional thing.

In any case, what happens here? Okay, you read into `ary[0]` a pointer into `temp`'s buffer. Now you get your next argument. *Best case*, `ary[0]` and `ary[1]` now point to the same argument and you've lost the first one. Worst case, `temp` had to reallocate and now `ary[0]` is already a dangling pointer.

Regardless, at the end of `getArgs()`, `temp` is destroyed, and now all your likely-not-even-different pointers are dangling.

That's bad. You'll need to come up with some different.

Comment: After doing some research I found the "_strdup" function. I substituted the "const_cast<char*>" for "_strdup" and it worked. Although this is working, is it still bad design?

Comment: @nhershy _"is it still bad design?"_ Definitely.

Comment: You really know how to boost the confidence of a novice programmer. Good job.

Comment: @nhershy Simply use `std::string` instead of `char*` or `char[]` array.

Comment: I'm working on creating a simple Shell program in c++ on Linux. I'm using the char* because in a moment I'll need to use the execvp() function which takes a char*, which is why I'm setting up my program this way.